# Python groupby id and datetime(only date and hour)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have dateframe list data like as below:

```
[
{"at": 2023-01-13 16:37, "id": 2},
{"at": 2023-01-13 16:38, "id": 2},
{"at": 2023-01-12 10:03, "id": 2},
{"at": 2023-01-11 10:45, "id": 2},
{"at": 2023-01-13 16:02, "id": 3},
]
```

I want to group this df with id and at but at must be created by date and hour.
The data that I want must be as below.

```
[
{"id": 2, "at": 2023-01-13- 16:00:00},
{"id": 2, "at": 2023-01-12- 10:00:00},
{"id": 2, "at": 2023-01-11- 10:00:00},
{"id": 3, "at": 2023-01-13- 16:00:00}
]
```

How can I do that with pandas? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `date` and `hour` the use `drop_duplicated`.

```
df['at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['at']).dt.to_period('H').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d- %H:%M:%S")
df_new = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['at', 'id'])
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
                     at  id
0  2023-01-13- 16:00:00   2
2  2023-01-12- 10:00:00   2
3  2023-01-11- 10:00:00   2
4  2023-01-13- 16:00:00   3
```

And if you want back to `list` of `dict`s.

```
>>> df_new.to_dict('records')
[{'at': '2023-01-13- 16:00:00', 'id': 2},
 {'at': '2023-01-12- 10:00:00', 'id': 2},
 {'at': '2023-01-11- 10:00:00', 'id': 2},
 {'at': '2023-01-13- 16:00:00', 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: I want to create loop and get value in for after df_new? How can I do?

Comment: @MehmetSerkanEkinci, Do you want this: `for dct in df_new.to_dict('records'):
    print(dct)`. you can get any `dict` like the above.

Answer (score 1):

If need aggregate some function use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html)    :

```
df['at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['at'])
#some aggregae function - e.g. size
df.groupby(['id', df['at'].dt.floor('H')]).size()
```

If need remove duplicates use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for convert minutes and seconds to `00:00` and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['at'])

df = df.assign(at = df['at'].dt.floor('H')).drop_duplicates()
print (df)
                   at  id
0 2023-01-13 16:00:00   2
2 2023-01-12 10:00:00   2
3 2023-01-11 10:00:00   2
4 2023-01-13 16:00:00   3
```

If need strings format of datetimes use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['at'])

df = (df.assign(at = df['at'].dt.floor('H')
                             .dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d- %H:%M:%S"))
        .drop_duplicates())
print (df)
                     at  id
0  2023-01-13- 16:00:00   2
2  2023-01-12- 10:00:00   2
3  2023-01-11- 10:00:00   2
4  2023-01-13- 16:00:00   3
```

Last for lsit of dictionaries with swapped order use sublist and [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (df[['id','at']].to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'id': 2, 'at': '2023-01-13- 16:00:00'},
 {'id': 2, 'at': '2023-01-12- 10:00:00'},
 {'id': 2, 'at': '2023-01-11- 10:00:00'}, 
 {'id': 3, 'at': '2023-01-13- 16:00:00'}
```